# Push from an SKScene to a view controller

Tags: uiviewcontroller, sprite-kit

I'm trying to do the following:

```
SKTransition *reveal = [SKTransition pushWithDirection:SKTransitionDirectionDown duration:0.5];
SKView *skv = (SKView *)self.view.window.rootViewController.view;
[self.view presentScene:skv.scene transition:reveal];
```

but it doesn't work, I get a SIGABRT Error. What can I use to get the same effect. I can use dismissViewController but then how do I use the pushWithDirection effect.

Comment: Where is the current scene presented? And why are you trying to push to the view controller, are you just trying to replace the current scene with a new one or are you trying to achieve something else?

Comment: is this the first scene? If so you may need to first present a dummy scene for the other scene to transition in. The scene will not slide in over/under a uikit view because the skview starts out entirely black.

Comment: is you're issue the fact that you are not seeing the SKTransition when presenting the scene? Yeah, it's not clear at all what you're issue is.

Comment: Sorry. When it gets to this the program stops and I get a sigbart

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure why you want to push to the view controller. If you just want to transition to a new scene you can do this from within the scene, without going near the parent view controller:

```
    YourScene *nextScene = [[YourScene alloc] initWithSize:self.size];
    SKTransition *reveal = [SKTransition pushWithDirection:SKTransitionDirectionDown duration:3.0];
    [self.view presentScene:nextScene transition:reveal];
```

If you do want to call this from the view controller you can add the view controller as a property in your scene:

```
#import "YourViewController.h"

@property (nonatomic,weak) YourViewController *viewController;
```

In your view controller when you set up your initial scene, assign the view controller to that attribute:

```
yourScene.viewController = self;
```

Then, from within the scene you can call methods on the view controller:

```
[viewController yourMethod];
```

which is:

```
//YourViewController.h
#import "YourScene.h"

...

-(void)yourMethod;


//YourViewController.m

...

-(void)yourMethod
{
    YourScene *nextScene = [[YourScene alloc] initWithSize:self.size];
    nextScene.viewController = self;
    SKTransition *reveal = [SKTransition pushWithDirection:SKTransitionDirectionDown duration:3.0];
    [yourSKView presentScene:nextScene transition:doors ];
}
```